# Find and replace content between XML tags from another file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, adobe-indesign

What i'm trying to accomplish is:
I want to update 10.000 prices in my indesign catalog automaticly.
The only way to do this, is to use XML.
When I label my table cells in indesign i can export an XML file which looks like this.

```
    -<Root>
-<Artikel>
-<Tabel aid:tcols="5" aid:trows="6" aid:table="table" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="5" aid:crows="1">.: Rollerflam </Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="5" aid:crows="1"/>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="79.29730708729332"/>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="65.97828346376967">Artikel code</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="144.56692913385828">Omschrijving</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="42.519685039370074">Prijs / st.</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="34.01574803149606">PG</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="3" aid:ccolwidth="79.29730708729332"/>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="65.97828346376967">AIRK7274</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="144.56692913385828">Rollerflampost </Cel>
-<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="42.519685039370074">

<AIRK7274>717,00</AIRK7274>

</Cel>

<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="3" aid:ccolwidth="34.01574803149606">-</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="65.97828346376967">AIRK7275</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="144.56692913385828">Rollerflampost met lastoebehoren</Cel>
+<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="42.519685039370074">
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="65.97828346376967">AIRK7277</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="144.56692913385828">Rollerflampost +las-en snijtoebehoren</Cel>
-<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="42.519685039370074">

<AIRK7277>1055,00</AIRK7277>

</Cel>
</Tabel>
</Artikel>

-<Artikel>
-<Tabel aid:tcols="5" aid:trows="7" aid:table="table" xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="5" aid:crows="1">.: Junior flessen </Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="5" aid:crows="1"/>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="79.29730708729332"/>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="65.97828346376964">Artikel code</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="144.56692913385828">Omschrijving</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="42.519685039370074">Prijs / st.</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="34.01574803149606">PG</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="79.29730708729332"/>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="65.97828346376964">AIRK7272</Cel>
<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="144.56692913385828">Fles met vulling van 2.30m³ zuurstof</Cel>
-<Cel aid:table="cell" aid:ccols="1" aid:crows="1" aid:ccolwidth="42.519685039370074">

<AIRK7272>345,00</AIRK7272>

</Cel>
```

These are only a few articles.
Now i have a list of all these Articles with tags which looks like this

```
<AIRK7274>222</AIRK7274>
<AIRK7275>222</AIRK7275>
<AIRK7277>1055</AIRK7277>
<AIRK7272>345</AIRK7272>
<AIRK7271>309</AIRK7271>
<AIRK7276>310</AIRK7276>
<AIRK7270>310</AIRK7270>
<AIR01150>42</AIR01150>
<AIR02150>42</AIR02150>
<AIR08193>42</AIR08193>
<AIR08197>42</AIR08197>
<AIR73142>39,5</AIR73142>
<AIRK7250>291</AIRK7250>
<AIRK7280>435</AIRK7280>
<BI1410>15,746</BI1410>
```

Is it possible to replace the content between the XML tags of the indesign file with the content of my file?
I've read about XML parser and regex but I don't really understand it yet.
Could anyone try to give me a good explanation on this and tell me if it's possible what i'm trying to achieve? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible in the general case. However, specify, what language do you use for xml processing.

Comment: I think you mean this line  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Loic

I think i found the answer.
I removed

```
xe.contents = String(Number ( String(tag).replace (/,/g, "." ) )*2).replace (/\./g, "," );
```

and replaced it with

```
xe.contents = String(tag).replace (/,/g, "." ) .replace (/\./g, "," );
```

It seems to work and problem is solved thank you Loic for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach by access the InDesign Scripting DOM:

```js
var main = function() {
 var doc = app.properties.activeDocument,
 root, xe, price,
 tags = <tags>
<AIRK7274>222</AIRK7274>
<AIRK7275>222</AIRK7275>
<AIRK7277>1055</AIRK7277>
<AIRK7272>345</AIRK7272>
<AIRK7271>309</AIRK7271>
<AIRK7276>310</AIRK7276>
<AIRK7270>310</AIRK7270>
<AIR01150>42</AIR01150>
<AIR02150>42</AIR02150>
<AIR08193>42</AIR08193>
<AIR08197>42</AIR08197>
<AIR73142>39,5</AIR73142>
<AIRK7250>291</AIRK7250>
<AIRK7280>435</AIRK7280>
<BI1410>15,746</BI1410>
</tags>, tag, xes;
 
 
 if ( !doc ) return;
 
 root = doc.xmlElements[0];
 
 tags = tags.children(), n = tags.length();
 
 while ( n-- ) {
  tag = tags[n];
  xes = root.evaluateXPathExpression ( ".//"+ String(tag.name()) );
  if ( xes.length ) {
   xe = xes[0];
   xe.contents = String(Number ( String(tag).replace (/,/g, "." ) )*2).replace (/\./g, "," );
  }
 }
}


var u;

app.doScript ( "main()",u,u,UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "The Script" );
```

[image: Before script is run]
[image: After Script is run. Prices get doubled…]

Comment: Thanks a lot Loic! There's only one more thing i would want to achieve and that's to have every price shown with 2 decimals.

For example:

When the price says "717,45" it returns the price in indesign as "717,45"

When the price says "717,00" it returns the price in indesign as "717"

Does anyone have a fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the "times 2" was an example of what you could do. To "round" numbers when needed, they are many ways but a quick fix could consist in :

```js
xe.contents = String(Number ( String(tag).replace (/,/g, "." ) )*2).replace (/\./g, "," ).replace ( ',00', '' );
```

Comment: Thanks Loic for your respond but i think you misread the question or probably I didn't explain it well.
I don't want it to round the prices. 
So when i put "717,00" in the script indesign returns "717" and not "717,00" like i want it to do. Is there a way for indesign to return exact what I've put between the tags?